Closedness of conical hull of a polyhedral convex set
Given a set $S$ in an Euclidean space, we define the conical hull of $S$ as
$${\rm coni}S=\{\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_ix_i:x_i\in S,\lambda_i\ge0,k\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$
Following this Why the cone generated by a closed convex set containing the origin may not be closed?, we know that the conical hull of a closed, convex set may not be closed. However if $S$ is convex, compact and does not contain $0$, then its conical hull is closed (see, Proposition 1.4.7 of the book Convex Analysis and Minimization Algorithms by Jean-Baptiste Hiriart-Urruty, Claude Lemaréchal, 1993).
Now we assume that $S$ is a polyhedral convex set that does not contain $0$. Then $S$ is closed but not necessarily compact. In this case, can we deduce that the conical hull of $S$ is closed? Thanks for your help.

For a counterexample consider
$$
S:=\Big\{x\in\mathbb R^2:\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}x\leq\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix}\Big\}=\{x\in\mathbb R^2:x_1\leq -1\}\,.
$$
Obviously, $S$ is polyhedral by definition and $0\not\in S$. However $${\rm coni}\,S=\{x\in\mathbb R^2:x_1<0\}\cup\{0\}\tag1$$ is not closed; to see this explicitly, note $(0,1)^T\in\overline{{\rm coni}\,S}\setminus {\rm coni}\,S$.
To give some more detail let us quickly verify that (1) holds; the claim about closedness then follows as $(0,1)^T\not\in {\rm coni}\,S$ but $(-\frac1n,1)^T\in {\rm coni}\,S$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ so $(0,1)^T=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-\frac1n,1)^T\in\overline{{\rm coni}\,S}$.
First, $\supseteq$ in (1)  holds because $x=(-x_1)(-1,\frac{-x_2}{x_1})^T\in\mathbb R_+\cdot S\subseteq$ (actually $=$) ${\rm coni}\,S$ for all $x$ with $x_1<0$. For $\subseteq$ consider any combination $x=\sum_i\lambda_ix_i$ with $\lambda_i\geq 0$ (w.l.o.g. $\lambda_j>0$ for some $j$), $x_i\in S$. Then $$x_1=\sum_i\lambda_i(x_i)_1\leq\sum_i-\lambda_i\leq-\lambda_j<0\,,$$ as desired.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer.
